# Analog to curl's --data-binary switch in jmeter's HTTP Request

Tags: curl, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I've got a working curl request that goes as so:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" -X POST --data-binary @sample.bin http://127.0.0.1:31415/test
```

`sample.bin` holds binary data.

In my jmeter test plan, I have "sample.bin" stored in `FILENAME`. This is what I put into the body of my HTTP Request:

```
${__eval( ${__FileToString(${FILENAME})})}
```

Unsurprisingly, this isn't working out. How can I emulate the --data-binary switch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, after RTFM carefully yet another time, I discovered that if [it is a POST or PUT or PATCH request and there is a single file whose 'Parameter name' attribute (below) is omitted, then the file is sent as the entire body of the request, i.e. no wrappers are added](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_parms).

Thus, putting `${FILENAME}` under file path in the "Send Files with the request" section (while leaving its paramter name empty and specifying an encoding) did the trick for me:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer!